# How to catch ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in javascript

Tags: javascript, iot, fetch-api

The Web Application I am developing needs to fetch data from a number of different IOTs within the local network, e.g.,

```
const response = await fetch("https://192.168.0.245/api/auto/login", options);
```

Since it is an https connection, and each IOT carries a self-signed SSL cert, therefore, the fetch() above will throw an error "TypeError: Failed to fetch" (since the cert has not yet been accepted), and the application will show the following in the browser's console

```
OPTIONS https://192.168.0.245/api/auto/login net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

What I need is to be able to catch this error in javascript. Specifically I need to be able to catch different errors like ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR or ERR_CONNECITON_REFUSED... etc. so I can show different error messages accordingly.

Unfortunately the fetch() function always throw the same "TypeError: Failed to fetch" exception under all these three different errors above.

Is there anyway I can catch this specific ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID exception?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it 100% mandatory to do it on the client side? Maybe you could proxy the requests through a server side script with better tooling. Like curl for example.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [fetch pollyfill code](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js), which should function the same as the native browser implementation (though the error messages are different). It doesn't include information about the specific error encountered. There are [two](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L466) [lines](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L471) that throw `TypeError`s and they both look like this:

```js
reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'))
```

So you just get an error message and no other information. And looking at the documentation for [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError), you don't get any extra information beyond what's available with a simple `Exception`. `TypeError` is what the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) requires to be thrown in this case.

You might be able to find another library that reports errors more specifically. I searched around a bit, but it's hard to find out whether a library has that feature just from documentation. You'll probably have to try them out and see what kind of error reporting they provide. Here are a couple options:

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

Or you could try implementing a solution using `XMLHttpRequest` directly. The `fetch` pollyfill code is a good starting point for that. You could fork that project and add some `console.log`s to see what kind of errors it reports.

Answer (score -3):

If Your Internet connection is not secure then may b it will give this error.means it is not https.

Or you can remove ssl Certificate from your server side. so your request format should be like "http://192.168.0.245/api/auto/login".